# JavaScript regular expressions: `/x.*y/` versus `/x(?=.*y)/`

Tags: javascript, regex

Need your help to understand when to use what. Both `/x.*y/`  and `/x(?=.*y)/`  are giving the same result (`true`) when used with method `test()` on string `"sxcvgyb"`.

Comment: If you're just checking for a boolean result (match or no match), they're equivalent.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gisqMQ/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/nEEYZ6/1 ; check the explanation panel to the right.

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/x.*y/` and `/x(?=.*y)/` are identical for your purposes, when using the `test` method.

The latter uses [a regular expression "look-ahead" group `(?=...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) and thus does not technically capture the `.*y` when matching, but this has no perceivable effects when you only need to know whether a match existed or not.

**TL;DR:** choose the shorter regex, `/x.*y/`.

```js
// Identical when using `RegExp#test`
console.log(/x.*y/    .test('xylophone')) //=> true
console.log(/x(?=.*y)/.test('xylophone')) //=> true

// Different when using `RegExp#exec`
console.log(/x.*y/    .exec('xylophone')) //=> [ 'xy' ]
console.log(/x(?=.*y)/.exec('xylophone')) //=> [ 'x' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using with `test` method, the result will be the same in this case:

> **RegExp.prototype.test()**
>
> The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.
>
> **Returns**
>
> true ***if there is a match*** between the regular expression and the
>   specified string; ***otherwise***, false.
>
> Ref: [Developer Mozilla - RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

For example, take a look here:

```js
const str = "sxcvgyb"

const test1 = RegExp(/x.*y/).test(str);
const result1 = str.match(/x.*y/);

const test2 = RegExp(/x(?=.*y)/).test(str);
const result2 = str.match(/x(?=.*y)/);

console.log('1st regex, is there a match? ', test1);
console.log('1st regex, what was matched? ', result1);
console.log('2nd regex, is there a match? ', test2);
console.log('2nd regex, what was matched? ', result2);
```

They both match something, thus `test` result is true. But if you look to what was actually matched, you can see the difference of them.

If you want to understand a bit more about their difference, [@gyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7256039/gyre)'s answer is good in explaining the "look-ahead" group.

And as [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) suggested, I also recommend you to use a online tester such as [regex101](http://regex101.com) and see what your regex does. Understand it even better looking closely to the explanation panel.